# Laravel - Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have the followings tables in my db: 
  
**connections** 
id 
owner_id

**owners** 
id 
room_id

**rooms** 
id 
room_number

I want to refer to room_number from my connections table through the owner_id. I tried with hasManyThrough relation but it works in the opposite way (from rooms table to fields in connections table). How should I build relations and what kind of relation should I put in my App\Connections?

Comment: What exactly do you have (ID of what?) and what exactly you'd like to get?

Comment: I have the tables above with relations between them. So connections table has access to owners table, and owners table has access to rooms table. But now I want to get room_number being in a connections table. E.g. connections->owners->rooms->room_number (but I know that it doesn't work in this way)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it. I had to put the following relations in Apps: 
Connections.php

```
public function owners()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Owners', 'owner_id');
}
```

Owners.php

```
public function connections()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Connections');
}

public function rooms()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Rooms', 'room_id');
}
```

Rooms.php

```
public function owners()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Owners');
}
```

And now when I added line below to my ConnectionsController.php

```
$connections = Connections::with('owners')->paginate(5);
```

I can refer in my index.blade writing:

```
@foreach($connections as $element)
    {{ $element->owners->rooms->room_number }}
@endforeach
```

@AlexeyMezenin Sorry for the fuss.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you have connection IDs and you want to get room numbers.

First, define relationships. In `Room` model:

```
public function owners()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Owner::class);
}
```

In `Owner` model:

```
public function connections();
{
    return $this->hasMany(Connection::class);
}
```

To get room numbers by connection IDs:

```
$connectionIds = [12, 15, 20];
$roomNumbers = Room::whereHas('owners.connections', function($q) use($connectionIds) {
        $q->whereIn('id', $connectionIds);
    })->pluck('room_number');
```

Comment: @Patryk B I'd deleted my post as this should answer your question.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin I'm pretty sure that your solution works but I've put the idea below which in my opinion lets to get room_number in easier way.